# How do I return the name of sheet with a variable on it in a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have a cell on sheet 1 return the name of the sheet the variables 'r1' (on sheet2) or 'r2' (on sheet3) are referenced from, if they meet qualifications. What I currently have is:

```
Public Function whichsheet(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String


If Application.Sum(r1) > 0 Then
    whichsheet = whichsheet & Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name

End If

If Application.Sum(r2) > 0 Then
    whichsheet = whichsheet & Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name

End If

End Function
```

Where  Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name is currently a placeholder that pulls the name of the first sheet, "sheet1" rather than "sheet1" and/or "sheet2".

Comment: `Application.Caller` actually pulls the cell that's being calculated; it *happens* to be a range on Sheet1, but if you do `=whichsheet(A1,B12)` somewhere in Sheet42, it will be a range on Sheet42.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will return the sheet name of the ranges as they are passed.

```
Public Function whichsheet(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String


If Application.Sum(r1) > 0 Then
    whichsheet = whichsheet & r1.Parent.Name

End If

If Application.Sum(r2) > 0 Then
    whichsheet = whichsheet & r2.Parent.Name

End If

End Function
```

Comment: @dGottwik after a few(15) more minutes Stack Overflow will let you mark this as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer. Please do so as it will remove this question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: I saw that, and I'll do so in 15. Thanks again